# connectionDidFinishLoading calls before image has downloaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiimage, nsurlconnection

I am trying to retrieve a Facebook profile picture, however I am having trouble being able to check when the image has been downloaded?

First I create a variable.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *imageData;
```

Than I start the connection.

```
-(void)getUserPicture {

//Grab user profile picture
imageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; // the image will be loaded in here
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", userId];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest =
[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                                 delegate:self];
    if (!urlConnection) NSLog(@"Failed to download picture");


}
```

After that I try to check when it is done so I can upload the file to my backend, however my problem is `connectionDidFinishLoading` calls almost instantly before the image has downloaded.

```
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    imageData = [NSMutableData data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [imageData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    userPicture = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        NSLog(@"%@",userPicture); //this returns null :(

    }
```

The weird thing is if I call this method twice, the `NSLog` doesn't return null, it actually returns the photo. So why is `connectionDidFinishedLoading` calling before the image has downloaded from Facebook?

Comment: place your `userPicture = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];` in your didReceiveData.

Comment: @SASmith No, that's a very bad idea. Unless the image is tiny, you very likely have not received all of the data at that point.

Comment: @Rob, I am not sure if it calls before it has downloaded all I know is my NSLOG returns null, the first time the method calls, than if I recall the method the image loads??

Comment: Also, in `didReceiveResponse`, look at the `NSURLResponse` object. Notably, if the status code is not 200, then you have a server problem (or a malformed request causing server error). Finally, did you implement `connection:didFailWithError:` delegate method, too?

Comment: @Rob, First of all this method is in my ViewController class which all my other classes are subclassed from I think, so each time a view loads for any of my ViewControllers this method gets called. I am not sure if this makes a difference. Second, when the method is first loaded, the console returns this http://postimg.org/image/i7bi085il/. Then, if I load a different view controller, the method is called again and the console returns this http://postimg.org/image/fr9vegxxn/. So whats weird is it actually gives me the image fine aslong as its called twice instead of once?

Comment: Also, I tried another method using the Facebook Graph and I still have the same problem, however here on the docs it says "by default this edge will return a 302 redirect to your picture image. To get access to the data about the picture, please include redirect=false in your query." So is this what is causing the problem? Here is the link to the docs. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly neither `NSURLConnection` nor the Facebook API, but rather how you're calling it. But, your question doesn't include enough information for us to diagnose it.

So, first, expand your methods to include more diagnostic information, for example:

```
// check the response header when we receive the response

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    imageData = [NSMutableData data];

    // if `statusCode` is not 200, show us what it was ...

    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
        int statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
        if (statusCode != 200) {
            NSLog(@"Status code was %ld, but should be 200.", (long)statusCode);
            NSLog(@"response = %@", response);
        }
    }
}

// make sure to detect and report any errors

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
}

// when you're done, if we fail to create `UIImage`, then it obviously
// wasn't an image, so let's see what it was.

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    userPicture = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    // if not an image, then ...

    if (!userPicture) {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if (responseString) {
            // if it was a string, show it to us ...

            NSLog(@"did not receive image: responseString = %@", responseString);
        } else {
            // if neither a string nor image data, then what was it ...

            NSLog(@"did not receive image: imageData = %@", imageData);
        }
    }

    // By the way, I'd expect to see you do something here to update the UI with the image;
    // all of these delegate methods were called asynchronously, so you have
    // to do something here that triggers the update of the UI, e.g.
    //
    // self.imageView.image = userPicture
}
```

By the way, I typed the above without the benefit of Xcode's syntax checking and the like, so don't be surprised if there are some errors there. But worry less about the actual code and focus on the the three diagnostic pillars this illustrates: 1. Look at the response headers and make sure they're ok, not reporting some non-200 status code; 2. Implement delegate that will report networking errors; and 3. If image conversion failed, then you obviously didn't receive an image, so stop and figure out what you actually received. (Often if the server had trouble fulfilling your request, the response is actually HTML or something like that which tells you *why* it had problems. If you don't look at it, you're flying blind.)

Second, you can watch the network connection by using [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) (or something like that). Run the app on the simulator and then watch the network connection as the app runs.

Third, if you're still having problems, create a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Namely, we don't want to see all of your code, but you should instead create the simplest possible example that manifests the problem you describe. Don't ask us to pour through tons of code, but rather make it as absolutely bare-bones as possible.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure why connectionDidFinishLoading is getting called instantly after you set the connection, but I may be able to help you work around the issue.

Try this:

```
-(UIImage *) getImageFromURL:(NSString *)fileURL {

    UIImage * result;

    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
    result = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    return result;
}
```

Where fileURL is the a string with the url.

If you want to perform an action after the request is sent try this instead:

```
-(UIImage *) getImageFromURL:(NSString *)fileURL {

    UIImage * result;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

        NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
        result = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        return result;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //code for operation after download
        });

    });
}
```

Let me know how it goes

Comment: No, moving to a synchronous, non-cancelable `dataWithContentsOfURL` is not an improvement. If you want to suggest something simpler, maybe `sendAsynchronousRequest` or better, if iOS 7 and later, `NSURLSession`. But this is not an improvement over the OPs code, IMHO.